# Excel Query Won't Update

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql

I have put a query that connects to SQL Server into an Excel spreadsheet (formatted as a table). I update this query daily. Today, when I tried to refresh the query, it generated an error and would not load new data.

The error says:

> "This won't work because it would move cells in a table on your worksheet."

All the research I've done on this error seems to relate to users attempting to insert rows, but that's not what I'm doing.

My query will only return two rows, plus the headers. It's not possible for the query to return anything more, so cells shouldn't move in the table.

Any suggestions to solve this error?

Comment: Are you using the in-built functionality "Data-connection" for this or is it a VBA script? I'll have a little play around and see if I can replicate it in any way.

Comment: I'm using the "Data" tab. Get Data > From Database > From SQL Server Database > Click Advanced Options > Type Query

Comment: Sorry I had no luck, I don't suppose you changed the query at all from previous runs?

Comment: Nope, just trying to refresh the same query from the prior day. I've deleted that query connection and added a new one (I've actually gone through this a few times). It'll work for a few days (potentially for a few weeks), then it'll throw the error again.

Comment: I'll keep refreshing a test case to see if it happens for me. Would you be opposed to a macro-enabled workbook with a script executing the query and dumping the results? _I could knock up a quick script as an example later if that's an option_